# Authlete api with Identity Server4

Tags: authlete

We are trying to use Authlete api with Identity Server4 to create and authorize access token but I can't seem to figure out how we can setup with .NET Core?

Comment: Authlete, Inc. released a NuGet package, [Authlete.Authlete](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Authlete.Authlete), which is a library to communicate with [Authlete APIs](https://docs.authlete.com). Its source code is located at https://github.com/authlete/authlete-csharp. Authlete, Inc. will release examples of an authorization server / OpenID provider and an resource server which use the NuGet package on GitHub soon. The examples use ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IdentityServer4](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4) is software written in C#. If you want to call [Web APIs](https://docs.authlete.com/) of [Authlete](https://www.authlete.com/) from C#, you can use [authlete-csharp](https://github.com/authlete/authlete-csharp) library (which is available as [Authlete.Authlete](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Authlete.Authlete) NuGet package). The API reference of authlete-csharp library is available [here](https://authlete.github.io/authlete-csharp/).

The following are sample implementations of an authorization server & OpenID provider and a resource server which use authlete-csharp library.

- [csharp-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/csharp-oauth-server) - an authorization server & OpenID provider implementation written in C# that supports [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/).
- [csharp-resource-server](https://github.com/authlete/csharp-resource-server) - a resource server implementation written in C# that includes an implementation of [UserInfo Endpoint](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo) whose specification is defined in [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

The following article is an introduction to csharp-oauth-server and csharp-resource-server.

- *"[OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect implementation in C# (Authlete)](https://medium.com/@darutk/oauth-2-0-and-openid-connect-implementation-in-c-authlete-8a8f9efc9361)"*

Basically, if you use Authlete, you don't have to use IdentityServer4. However, if you have strong reasons to use IdentityServer4, some parts of Authlete APIs may work for your purposes.

For example, if you want to use Authlete just as a generator of access tokens, Authlete's `/api/auth/token/create` API may work.

```cs
// An instance of IAuthleteApi interface.
IAuthleteApi api = ......

// Prepare a request to /api/auth/token/create API.
var request = new TokenCreateRequest
{
    GrantType = ......,
    ClientId  = ......,
    Subject   = ......,
    Scopes    = ......,
    ......
};

// Call /api/auth/token/create API.
TokenCreateResponse response = await api.TokenCreate(request);

// If the API call successfully generated an access token.
if (response.Action = TokenCreateAction.OK)
{
    // The newly issued access token.
    string accessToken = response.AccessToken;
}
```

If you want to use Authlete as a storage for metadata of client applications, `/api/client/*` APIs (and "Client ID Alias" feature) may work.

```cs
// An instance of IAuthleteApi interface.
IAuthleteApi api = ......

// Prepare a request to /api/client/create API.
var request = new Client
{
    ClientName   = ......,
    Developer    = ......,
    ClientType   = ......,
    RedirectUris = ......,
    ......
};

// Call /api/client/create API. Client ID and client secret
// are automatically generated and assigned by Authlete.
Client client = await api.CreateClient(request);

// You can update client information by calling
// /api/client/update/{clientId} API.
client = await api.UpdateClient(client);
```

Authlete manages multiple services. *Service* here is an instance which corresponds to one authorization server & OpenID provider. Even a service itself can be managed by `/api/service/*` APIs.

```cs
// An instance of IAuthleteApi interface.
IAuthleteApi api = ......

// Prepare a request to /api/service/create API.
var request = new Service
{
    ServiceName     = ......,
    Issuer          = ......,
    SupportedScopes = ......,
    ......
};

// Call /api/service/create API. A pair of API key and
// API secret to manage the service is automatically
// generated and assigned by Authlete.
Service service = await api.CreateService(request);

// You can update service information by calling
// /api/service/update/{serviceApiKey} API.
service = await api.UpdateService(service);
```

Although services and client applications can be managed by Authlete APIs, I recommend you use web consoles ([Service Owner Console](https://www.authlete.com/documents/so_console) & [Developer Console](https://www.authlete.com/documents/cd_console)) to manage them.

---

Many libraries including IdentityServer4 require programming for configuration of an authorization server itself, registration of client applications and database setup. I didn't want to do such things and finally decided to develop not a library but a SaaS (= APIs + permanent storage) in order to free developers from the burden. It was the reason Authlete was born. (I'm a co-founder of [Authlete, Inc.](https://www.authlete.com/))